# Changing Shape and Structure of Data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, data-preprocessing

I have the following dataset

| Office | Employee ID | Joining Date | Attrition Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 700237 | 27-11-2017 |  |
| AA | 700238 | 11-01-2018 |  |
| AA | 700252 | 14-02-2018 | 08-04-2018 |
| AB | 700287 | 18-01-2014 |  |
| AB | 700449 | 28-02-2014 | 17-04-2014 |

The idea is to add in Active Column if somebody joins and deduct if somebody resigns in any month and therefore want to change it in the following format using python

| Office | Month & Year | Active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | Jan-17 | 0 |
| AA | Feb-17 | 0 |
| AA | Mar-17 | 0 |
| AA | Apr-17 | 0 |
| AA | May-17 | 0 |
| AA | Jun-17 | 0 |
| AA | Jul-17 | 0 |
| AA | Aug-17 | 0 |
| AA | Sep-17 | 0 |
| AA | Oct-17 | 0 |
| AA | Nov-17 | 1 |
| AA | Dec-17 | 1 |
| AA | Jan-18 | 2 |
| AA | Feb-18 | 3 |
| AA | Mar-18 | 3 |
| AA | Apr-18 | 2 |
| AB | Jan-14 | 1 |
| AB | Feb-14 | 2 |
| AB | Mar-14 | 2 |
| AB | Apr-14 | 1 |

Please help.

Comment: populating data from starting of the year of the first joining date and going till last instant of joining/attrition for each office.....

Comment: make sense. there are only 28 days in february -> this is wrong `31-02-2014` the last line in your dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#convert columns to datetimes
df['Joining Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Joining Date'], dayfirst=True)
df['Attrition Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Attrition Date'], dayfirst=True)

#add new rows by first January of minimal year per groups
df1 = df.groupby('Office')['Joining Date'].min() - pd.offsets.DateOffset(month=1, day=1)
df = df.append(df1.reset_index()).sort_values(['Office','Joining Date'])


#replace missing values in Attrition Date by maximal date with next month
#replace missing values in Joining  Date by maximal date with next month
next_month = (df.groupby('Office')['Attrition Date'].transform('max') + 
               pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=1))
next_month1 = (df.groupby('Office')['Joining Date'].transform('max') + 
               pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=1))

df['Attrition Date'] = df['Attrition Date'].fillna(next_month).fillna(next_month1)


#explode start and end datetimes converted to months with years
f = lambda x: pd.date_range(x['Joining Date'], 
                            x['Attrition Date'], freq='M').strftime('%b-%y')
df['Month & Year'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)

#count number of Employee ID with omit missing values
df = (df.explode('Month & Year')
        .groupby(['Office','Month & Year'], sort=False)['Employee ID']
        .count()
        .reset_index(name='Active'))
```

---

```
print (df)
   Office Month & Year  Active
0      AA       Jan-17       0
1      AA       Feb-17       0
2      AA       Mar-17       0
3      AA       Apr-17       0
4      AA       May-17       0
5      AA       Jun-17       0
6      AA       Jul-17       0
7      AA       Aug-17       0
8      AA       Sep-17       0
9      AA       Oct-17       0
10     AA       Nov-17       1
11     AA       Dec-17       1
12     AA       Jan-18       2
13     AA       Feb-18       3
14     AA       Mar-18       3
15     AA       Apr-18       2
16     AB       Jan-14       1
17     AB       Feb-14       2
18     AB       Mar-14       2
19     AB       Apr-14       1
```

Comment: thanks for the help...i think there is just one issue.....After using this code...#explode start and end datetimes converted to months with years
f = lambda x: pd.date_range(x['Joining Date'], 
                            x['Attrition Date'], freq='M').strftime('%b-%y')
df['Month & Year'] = df.apply(f, axis=1).....I am getting the following value error

'Neither `start` nor `end` can be NaT'

Comment: @user9855045 - It means in some group is no `Attrition Date`, answer was edited by `next_month1` and `df['Attrition Date'] = df['Attrition Date'].fillna(next_month).fillna(next_month1)`